# How to change video source with just JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video

Here is my simple page (css not added):

```
<a onclick="PlayVideo('http://www.myhost.com/..../myVideo1.mp4');">Play Video 1</a>
<a onclick="PlayVideo('http://www.myhost.com/..../myVideo2.mp4');">Play Video 2</a>

<div id="xxxxxx">
    <div><a onclick="StopVideo();">X</a>
         <video id="video" width="520" height="360" controls></video>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    function PlayVideo(srcVideo) {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var source = document.createElement('source');   
        source.setAttribute('src', srcVideo);
        video.appendChild(source);
        video.play();
    }

    function StopVideo() {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
    }
</script>
```

When I click "Play Video 2" it's still playing video 1. So how do I switch the video source to play in same video element? I need just pure JavaScript if that's possible

Comment: You're adding more sources to the existing video element. You need to clear out the previously loaded sources, or better yet, create a new video element each time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to append new source. Just set new `src` attribute and call `video.load` function.

<s>See working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ced91p60/)</s>

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
source = document.getElementById('source');

function PlayVideo(srcVideo){
  video.pause();
  source.src = srcVideo;
  video.load();
  video.play();
}

function StopVideo(){
  document.getElementById('video').pause();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Changed `.setAttribute('src',srcVideo)` to `.src = srcVideo` because this is commonly used method to change source.

Comment: good example but it just doesn't work with files/url like   http://www.myhost.com/..../myVideo2.mp4

Comment: @VladP. Then it must be some problem with your host. I also tested it on my localhost (built using WAMP, XAMPP and Node.js) and it works properly.

Comment: it works/plays in my example in the question. I just cannot change the source. So it's not host problem

Comment: @VladP. Can you successfully change source in my fiddle? If yes, then copy-paste it and it sould work.

Comment: Oh. sorry for the confusion.. It does work.. Thank you very much.. I mark it as answered

Comment: @VladP. If you found my answer useful, consider upvoting it.